# How to turn off the LG Optimus L5 screen magnifier?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, screen, lg-optimus-l5

That is the problem. I've already made a hard reset (press power button + vol. down key then pressing the home key) without luck. The screen is stuck magnified and I can't do anything.

[image: screenshot]
<sup>Screenshot (click image for larger variant)</sup>

What can I do to get it back to normal?

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention it but I've already googled for this and I don't seem to find related issues or similar problems. I bought it like this so I don't know what the previous user installed or did to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you already did a factory reset, then I think that the problem lies in the `/system/build.prop`.

Are you rooted? If so, connect your phone to your PC, make sure you have ADB, and do this in a terminal:

```
adb pull /system/build.prop
```

In the `build.prop` file you just copied from the phone, look for `ro.sf.lcd_density`.
Change the number to something low, like 160 or 240. Save the file, and do this in a terminal to put it back onto the phone:

```
adb push build.prop /sdcard/build.prop
adb shell
su
cp /sdcard/build.prop /system/build.prop
chmod 0644 /system/build.prop
reboot
```

If you're not rooted, then you would probably have to do a firmware reflash; although I'm not familiar with LG's way of doing that.

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't check the anwers until today so I ended up completely reinstalling the ROM but I checked your solution and it was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you again!